# How to assign text size in sp value using java code

Tags: android, textview, text-size

If I assign an integer value to change a certain text size of a `TextView` using java code, the value is interpreted as pixel (`px`).

Now does anyone know how to assign it in `sp`?

Answer (score 601, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29

Example:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 65);
```

Comment: Since SP stands for scaled *pixels* you'll need to reduce the size by screen density.  It's easily done as follows:
SCREEN_DENSITY = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
yourView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (desiredTextHeightInSP / SCREEN_DENSITY);

Comment: The solution didn't work for me when I tried to collect SP from resources. PeteH, you got me on the right track! The following did the trick for me: ...
float textSize = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize) / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
myTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);

Comment: If you get the sp size from your resources, you should use COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, like this: `textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.my_text_size_in_sp));` Getting your text size this way will already convert SP to PX, taking both screen density and text scale factor in account.

Comment: The provided solution worked for me as shown. Thanks!

Comment: The actual answer did it for me, i dont why but suggestions from comments made my text go microscopic while trying to set sp tp 11

Answer (score 42):

Cleaner and more reusable approach is

define text size in `dimens.xml` file inside `res/values/` directory:

```
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_medium">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and then apply it to the `TextView`:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_medium));
```

Comment: I would argue that XML is not "in Java code" as the OP requested. This doesn't allow the code a way to set the font to something not already predetermined by the programmer.

Answer (score 37):

You can use a [`DisplayMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) object to help convert between pixels and scaled pixels with the [`scaledDensity` attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#scaledDensity).

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
pixelSize = (int)scaledPixelSize * dm.scaledDensity;
```

Comment: This will take the screen density scaling factor into account but not the text scale factor that the user may have specified via settings.  I believe @Santosh's solution will take this factor into account whereas this snippet does not.

Comment: But sometimes you are not able to use the method of @Santosh for example when you write a Paint into a canvas. Then this method comes handy and works pretty well, therefore thumbs up for these two answers!

Comment: @greg7gkb not true, documentation says ```may be adjusted in smaller increments at runtime based on a user preference for the font size``` so the font size **will** be taken into account.

Answer (score 21):

Based on the the source code of `setTextSize`:

```
public void setTextSize(int unit, float size) {
    Context c = getContext();
    Resources r;

    if (c == null)
        r = Resources.getSystem();
    else
        r = c.getResources();

    setRawTextSize(TypedValue.applyDimension(
        unit, size, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}
```

I build this function for calulating any demension to pixels:

```
int getPixels(int unit, float size) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(unit, size, metrics);
}
```

Where unit is something like `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP`.

Comment: the last method is a life saver.

Answer (score 17):

When the accepted answer doesn't work (for example when dealing with Paint) you can use:

```
float spTextSize = 12;
float textSize = spTextSize * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
```

Comment: ok, it work , That's what I want, thanks pomber  for sharing it !

Answer (score 13):

By default setTextSize, without units work in SP (scales pixel)

```
public void setTextSize (float size)
```

> Added in API level 1
> Set the default text size to the given value, interpreted as "scaled pixel" units. This
> size is adjusted based on the current density and user font size preference.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks @John Leehey and @PeterH:

```
desiredSp = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.desired_sp);
density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, desiredSp / density);
```

The thing is if you define R.dimen.desired_sp to 25 in your dimen.xml

1. On non-HD Device:
   desiredSp is still 25, density = 1
2. On HD Device(like Nexus 7 2nd Generation):
   desiredSp becomes 50 ish, density = 2

Answer (score 10):

```
semeTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 
                       context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_in_dp))
```

Comment: Please explain how setting the text size as pixel value (COMPLEX_UNIT_PX) will be helpful. OP wants to "assign text size in sp value"

Comment: if you use `COMPLEX_UNIT_PX` you need to divide density.

Comment: I think it's because getDimension already converted 'dp' to 'px'

Comment: I would argue that XML is not "in Java code" as the OP requested. This doesn't allow the code a way to set the font to something not already predetermined by the programmer.

Answer (score 4):

This is code for the convert **PX** to **SP** format.
100% Works

```
view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 24);
```

Comment: Doesn't this set the size based on the number of pixels while the OP asked how to set it in SP? How does this answer their question?

Answer (score 3):

From Api level 1, you can use the [`public void setTextSize (float size)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(float)) method.

From the documentation:

> Set the default text size to the given value, interpreted as "scaled
>   pixel" units. This size is adjusted based on the current density and
>   user font size preference.
>
> Parameters:
>   size -> float: The scaled pixel size.

So you can simple do:

```
textView.setTextSize(12); // your size in sp
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Kotlin** `'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'`, this way is useful

```
import android.util.TypedValue


.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12F)
```

here **12F = 12sp**

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the solutions and none giving acceptable results (maybe because I was working on a device with default very large fonts), the following worked for me (COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP = Device Independent Pixels):

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14);
```