# Android text around image bug

Tags: android, textview, imageview, word-wrap

By following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image), I was able to have text around an image. However, I have the following problem.

[image]

As you can see, the space for the image on top is displayed in every paragraph at the right. In the question someone had this problem and suggested to change 'ss.length()' for 'lines'. This seemed to work except if the first paragraph was too short, the next paragraph would overlap the image.

I modified the FlowTextHelper class slightly to use text from Html. This is the code I'm using:

```
public class FlowTextHelper {
    private static boolean mNewClassAvailable;

    /* class initialization fails when this throws an exception */
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan$LeadingMarginSpan2");
            mNewClassAvailable = true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            mNewClassAvailable = false;
        }
    }

    public static void tryFlowText(String text, View thumbnailView, TextView messageView, Display display, int addPadding){
        // There is nothing I can do for older versions, so just return
        if(!mNewClassAvailable) return;

        // Get height and width of the image and height of the text line
        thumbnailView.measure(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
        int height = thumbnailView.getMeasuredHeight();
        int width = thumbnailView.getMeasuredWidth() + addPadding;
        messageView.measure(width, height); //to allow getTotalPaddingTop
        int padding = messageView.getTotalPaddingTop();
        float textLineHeight = messageView.getPaint().getTextSize();

        // Set the span according to the number of lines and width of the image
        int lines =  (int)Math.round((height - padding) / textLineHeight);
        //SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
        //For an html text you can use this line:
        if(!text.equals("")) {
            SpannableStringBuilder ss = (SpannableStringBuilder) Html.fromHtml(text);
            ss.setSpan(new MyLeadingMarginSpan2(lines, width), 0, ss.length(), 0);
            messageView.setText(ss);
            messageView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); // links

            // Align the text with the image by removing the rule that the text is to the right of the image
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) messageView.getLayoutParams();
            int[] rules = params.getRules();
            rules[RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF] = 0;
        }
    }
}

public class MyLeadingMarginSpan2 implements LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2 {
    private int margin;
    private int lines;

    public MyLeadingMarginSpan2(int lines, int margin) {
        this.margin = margin;
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {
        return first ? margin : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLeadingMarginLineCount() {
        return lines;
    }

    @Override
    public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir,
                                  int top, int baseline, int bottom, CharSequence text,
                                  int start, int end, boolean first, Layout layout) {}
}
```

What is causing the space being repeated every paragraph and how can I get rid of it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For anyone wondering why this behavior happens, it's a bug in android: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38003

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've spend hours to solve this issue, but solved it with thanks to the answer found here: 
[text wrapping around image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313898/text-wrapping-around-image-in-android/)

Basically as follows:

First add a margin to your textview and set the text

```
final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)messageView.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(marginWidth, 0, 0, 0);
messageView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Then add an OnGlobalLayoutListener and in the onGlobalLayout() call you calculate how many lines actually need the margin. You split the lines in 2 separate spannables and add the Margin only to the first one:

```
        messageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener( new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                int linesCount = messageView.getLayout().getLineCount();
                // restore the margin
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                SpannableString spanS =  new  SpannableString ( Html.fromHtml(text) );

                if (linesCount <= lines) {
                    spanS.setSpan(new MyLeadingMarginSpan2(lines, width), 0, spanS.length(), 0);
                    messageView.setText(spanS);
                } else {
                    // find the breakpoint where to break the String.
                    int breakpoint = messageView.getLayout().getLineEnd(lines-1);

                    Spannable s1 = new SpannableStringBuilder(spanS, 0, breakpoint);
                    s1.setSpan(new MyLeadingMarginSpan2(lines, width), 0, s1.length(), 0);
                    Spannable s2 = new SpannableStringBuilder(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    Spannable s3 = new SpannableStringBuilder(spanS, breakpoint, spanS.length());
                    // It is needed to set a zero-margin span on for the text under the image to prevent the space on the right!
                    s3.setSpan(new MyLeadingMarginSpan2(0, 0), 0, s3.length(), 0);
                    messageView.setText(TextUtils.concat(s1, s2, s3));
                }

                // remove the GlobalLayoutListener
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                     messageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);                           
                 } else {
                     messageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                 }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It looks great. If I get a chance to go back to this problem, I will try it out.

Comment: Hi, where did you add OnGlobalLayoutListener? Is it in FlowTextHelper?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wrap text around an image, use this library [FlowTextView](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView).

The library performs well, and it can be used with a couple lines. However, it does not support screen pixel size for fonts. I found a workaround with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069810/how-to-assign-text-size-in-sp-value-using-java-code/2069906#2069906), so that you can convert pixel size to sp.

I hope this helps anyone and you don't waste as much time as me using the question from my original post.